# Selenium throws NoSuchElementException even with explicit wait

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, automation

I am trying to automate some web testing with Selenium. I have written a method that logs into the website (see `LoginToSite` below).

```
public async Task<bool> CanUserLogin()
{
    var driver = new FirefoxDriver(_config["driverPath"]);

    LoginToSite(driver);

    //unrelated stuff, removed for brevity
}

public void LoginToSite(IWebDriver driver)
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_config["siteUrl"]);

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    var result = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Name("name")));
    Console.WriteLine(result.Size);
}
```

Selenium throws this exception when I try to use `x => x.FindElement(By.Name("name"))`:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: *[name ="name"]
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<Name>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at REDACTED
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition, CancellationToken token)
```

I have followed the examples from the [selenium documentation on WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/), and cannot find any other reason why this is failing.

When the web driver is open, I can open the console and type `document.getElementsByName("name")[0]`, which returns the element correctly.

The page loads in under a second, and I am unable to find any other elements (for example, the same code throws the same exception when retrieving an element by ID).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is the element under any iframes or shadow root.

Comment: nope, it's a fairly simple hierarchy: html>body>div>div>div>input[name="name"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using Implicit wait

`driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 7);`

Comment: This works, thanks! Is there a pattern you're aware of in which this should be used? I don't want to add an implicit wait after every page load (for clean code reasons, as well as performance).

Comment: If you are using NUnit then you can under  [Setup] along with launching a browser, so it will run before every test